# In The Old Republic ship-based minigame, is there a way to destroy shielded targets?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In space combat how do you disable shield generators?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/43575/in-space-combat-how-do-you-disable-shield-generators)

In The Old Republic ship-based minigame, is there a way to destroy shielded targets? Most targets will go down after a bit of fire, or a missile -- there are a few targets on the larger ships that don't seem to take any damage.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot? I've been able to destroy pretty much everything (in the first 5 missions) in the ship games with no problem.