# In space combat, how do you disable shielded targets?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I'm playing the space battles and I can't seem to disable shielded targets. When I shoot at them (I assume it's them as they're yellow outlined reticules) they flash blue.

I'm guessing you need a technique in order to take them out, but I'm not sure what to try.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible to destroy them. It's just hard.

I had been curious about this as well and when I hit level 26, I loaded my ship up with a bunch of upgrades and went back to that starting mission, Balosar Outpost. You CAN blow up that shielded antenna on the bottom, and you don't need protons to do it.

When doing the mission, I saved a lot of my missiles for the antenna, and I launched missiles at it and fired at it whenever possible. On one of my last passes at it (probably put about 20 missiles in it, plus a lot of gunfire) it blew up and I briefly saw a bonus objective message appear in green text across the screen for destroying the antenna relay. Note that it was an "unadvertised" bonus, as I hadn't seen it in the quest log.

I was also able to do this on the Makem Te Assault against the shielded node on the destroyer, too. My ship is fully upgraded (for level 27) and it took about 30 missiles plus a lot of concentrated fire, along with the augment thing that has guns do more damage while shields regen slower. When it blew up, again I got a "hidden" bonus objective complete message.

Comment: Interesting. Wonder if that's intentional behavior.

Comment: I've found it out! It's a matter of range. You can only take out shielded targets from far away. So ideally with missiles, but you have to launch them from quite far out for them to connect without the blue flashes.

Comment: Really? I'm pretty sure I've finished off some of the targets when I was up close and personal. Will test again tonight!

Comment: Updating my answer since as of the latest patch, destroying the shielded node on Balosar Outpost no longer crashes the game.

Comment: Also, I definitely can finished of shielded targets from close range.

Comment: I've destroyed the bottom antenna at lvl 17 with grade 1 upgrades. I have had a lot of practice with my lvl 35 main, though.

Comment: I've been doing a lot of research and what I *think* the shielding means is that the hardpoint has innate per-hit damage reduction. It's the only viable explanation why fifteen seconds of 10x100 blaster fire does nothing to a frigate's shield generators and three concussion missiles blow one away.

Answer (score 2):

Missiles are the way, for instance for cartel listening station you have to save and use almost every missile on the bottoms spire if you wish to destroy that (is a bonus bonus mission). Warning! If you destroy the entire station the game WILL crash! Hope they fix it :(.

Comment: I wasn't aware that you could even destroy the entire station.

Comment: Crash has been fixed as of 4-jan-2012.

Answer (score 2):

They can be taken out by using the torpedos you get a lvl50.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: Targets that flash like that are heavily shielded. As near as I can tell, blasters simply have little to no effect (the only time I've seen different is in the shield generators on the Makem Te Assault) and they take a significant number of concussion missiles to crack, varying by mission and component.

For instance, the first tier mission frigates' shield generators fall to two missiles apiece, while at the later tier they require three hits; at the final mission some of the shielded hardpoints (which are also primary mission targets) take more than a full magazine apiece.

Proton Torpedoes, on the other hand, have a /very/ long lock time and will refuse to even start the lockon procedure against anything that isn't an appropriate target -- meaning capital ship shield generators, bridges and that bottom antenna of the space station -- but they *will* kill whatever they hit in one shot. Unfortunately, you can't fire a regular missile at anything that *can* be targeted with a PT unless the torpedo launcher is currently unloaded even if it would only take two concussion missiles to breach the shield generator...

Comment: I think this is correct, as I've never been able to destroy the antennae on the bottom of the space station

Comment: It is possible, at least for the antenna relay. Haven't been able to get enough time on target to try on a capital ship though. See my answer below.

Comment: I once thought the same, but nowadays I routinally destroy them.

Comment: Yeah. Answer amended.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fire missiles at any yellow-outlined reticules.

As I recall, missiles are fired by holding the right-mouse button until they lock on, then letting go of it.

Comment: I've tried that and it doesn't seem to have an effect. Perhaps you need to hit all 4 at the same time? In a single volley. Will try again.

Comment: @DavidYell Is this in a particular mission?  I thought I remember knocking out some shield generators in the space mission near Hutta using missiles.

Comment: You're describing torpedos, not missiles.

Answer (score 0):

They can be taken out with a high amount of missiles (20-40), or you can use the proton torpedo you get at level 50.

Comment: This is a repeat of the answers above.

Comment: @Resorath yet none of the answers are concise about both ways to blow up shielded targets. The other answers only mention one or the other. My answer gives both ways.