# Does targeting the bridge and engines of capital ships do anything?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

In the space missions, some of the targetable points on the capital ships (destroyers and frigates) seem to include the bridge and other points on the hull that are shielded (blue when hit by blasters).  Likewise, on the bottom of the space-station there is also a targetable point.

Is there any point to shooting these?  Does it disable the ship any more than by just killing turrets?  Some of them (the bridge and bottom of the station at least) seem nearly indestructible, as I can throw perhaps a dozen missiles (not enough?) at them and nothing happens.

---

**Addition:** As there seem to be hidden bonus missions, what are they and what do you need to destroy?  Do all of these "high-value" targets give their own bonus?  Just one per mission?

Comment: I was wondering this too, the space station in particular I targeted for a while with no results.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/43575/in-space-combat-how-do-you-disable-shielded-targets

Comment: Makes fire and smoke, lots of smoke, so much smoke - in space.

Comment: By level 25 or so, these become pretty easy to destroy if you've bought the vendor ship upgrades as well as the powerup thing that lets you do extra blaster damage by trading off shield regen. As long as you focus fire on them and save missiles, it's pretty easy to take out the shielded nodes on Balosar Outpost and Makem Te Assault.

Comment: From the sounds of it, when you get proton torpedoes it should be much easier to take out these targets.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes!  They are a pain to take out, but when you do, you will likely complete a bonus mission (all of the ones I've managed to blow up so far have) in addition to providing a nice chunk of XP.  The bottom of first cartel listening station for example will give you 500 points for the kill and just under 3000 for completing the bonus mission.  I try to save my missiles for those items in particular since they are definitely hardened targets.

Edit for additional info:  The space stations and capital ship bridges I have destroyed so far have been bonus missions all by themselves with no other targets.  Blow them up and you instantly get both the base experience and the bonus mission experience.  There can certainly be multiple bonus missions per encounter.  One listening station had the fighter ships, the communications relay (the hard point at the bottom), as well as satellites plus turrets.  Essentially, if you can target it, it CAN be blow up.  I try to blow up everything I can, and make a mental note of what triggers a bonus mission.  I haven't come across a good guide to all of the bonuses yet.  Only one way to find out - blow up ALL the things!

Comment: What's the bonus mission?  Just shoot the one bit of the station?

Comment: Note that there might be a level requirement for bonus missions. E.g. the satellites and turrets bonus mission (during Cartel Listening Station) is not active from the start, but activates somewhere around level 30. I already had a habit to blow them up long before I got bonus mission credits for doing so.

Answer (score 3):

On the **crippled destroyer** missions, obliterating the bridge of the main capital ship awards:

- Sarapin Assault (*Imperial*)

  - [Eliminate the Enemy Command](http://www.torhead.com/search/eliminate%20the%20enemy%20command), 2538 credits, 2970 XP (@ 25)
- Makem Te Assault (*Republic*)

  - ?

Destroying the target at the bottom of the **space station** awards:

- Cartel Listening Station (*Imperial*)

  - [Cripple Republic Communications](http://www.torhead.com/mission/gUWkMI0/cripple-republic-communications), 2538 credits, 2970 XP (@ 25)
- Balosar Outpost (*Republic*)

  - [Take Out the Communication Array](http://www.torhead.com/mission/ftjj8PF)(?)

Answer (score 0):

You can't target capital ship engines. I think you're referring to the shield generators. Both the bridge and generators are destructible. The generators the easier to kill of the two, I think. Later on you'll be able to buy the proton torpedo module from the space vendor, which allows you to acquire a lock on the blue reticule targets and one shot them with 1 of the 4 torpedos you get.